# Aspnet web site administration tool, Users table or aspnet_users table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Why do my users and roles end up in *Users* and *Roles* tables and not aspnet_users and aspnet_roles?

---

When I use the Aspnet web site administration tool (visualstudio->menu->project->aspnet configuration to add a user it ends up in the Users table; and new roles in the Roles table.

Everything I have read on the subject says aspnet_users and aspnnet_roles.

I am using aspnetmvc4 (beta), sqlserver2008r2, visualstudio2010.  I have created the aspnet_xxx-tables in the database through aspnet_regsql.exe.  I sniff sqlserver and get queries against Users and Roles.  It even creates an Applications table.

As per request, the membership part of web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
      minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/"
         name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Interesting!  Could you add the `<membership>` section of your application's Web.Config to the question?

Comment: What database does "DefaultConnection" point to?  `aspnetdb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Old school ASP.NET 2.0+ providers (`System.Web.XXX.SqlXXXProvider`)
--> Uses the *aspnet*_Users and *aspnet*_Roles tables, via stored procs.

The new Universal Providers (`System.Web.Providers.XXX`)
--> Uses the *Users* and *Roles* tables, via (EF-generated?) SQL.

More info here (from Mr Scott H):
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx