# Where is ASP.NET Storing User Data?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm seeing some strange behavior, and I'm sure there's a simple explanation for it that I just don't see.

Using Visual Studio 2012 RC, MVC 4, I created a standard Internet application (using Forms authentication).  I then used aspnet_regsql to add the membership tables to my database.  Then I updated the Web.config connection string to point to my custom database:

```
<add name="NewEdCoConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress2012;Initial Catalog=NewEdCo;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And, of course, updated the provider nodes in the Web.config to use that connection string.

It works fine.  I can launch the application in the usual IIS Express, register a user, login as that user, etc.  I kill the application, re-launch, and I can still login as that user.  So it's persisting the data.

However, in SQL Server Management Studio when I `SELECT * FROM` any of the aspnet_* tables, they don't contain any data.

Where is it persisting this data?

Comment: You probably not see the correct database. (ether you, ether you web application)

Comment: @Aristos: But what other database would it be?  That's the question.  I've tested the Web.config by changing the name of the connection string, which expectedly threw an error because the providers couldn't find a string by that name.  I ran another test by invalidating the connection string itself (specifying an incorrect initial catalog) and it continued to work.  So it's looking for that connection string _name_, but it's not using the actual connection string.  So what would it be using?

Comment: Do you have open the database called `NewEdCo`, or some other ? At least on my database the data are there :)

Comment: @Aristos: In SQL Management Studio?  There are no other databases on the server (other than `master` and whatnot).  But yes, that database exists and I'm explicitly selecting from it: `SELECT * FROM NewEdCo.dbo.aspnet_Users`

Comment: You must see it and in SQL management studio, if you not see it I think two cases, one that you do not have included in the list (but then the site can not see it also with this config) - you can add it, or second you have more than one sql instances running and you open the other one - the one you connect with your web.config

Comment: Do you know where is the file that you have create ? connect it to the sql managment.

Comment: @Aristos: Ok, now _this_ is strange. Your comment made me think of something else to test. I noticed that SQL Management Studio was connecting to `DAVIDDONAHU436A\SQLEXPRESS2012` (that's the name the machine was given during the Windows 8 install, and I've verified is the name of the machine in question), while the connection string was going to `localhost\sqlexpress2012`. I connected to `localhost\sqlexpress2012` in SQL Management Studio and, lo and behold, there's the data (including the tables LosManos mentions in his answer). Two SQL instances differentiated by _hostname_ on the same host?

Comment: So you see, I have right at the first, you look somewhere else :)

Comment: @Aristos: True, and it's a pretty surprising somewhere else at that.  Worth a different question, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be as @Aristos alluded in comments on the question above.  It *was* using a different database, though I'm currently unsure *how*.  The difference between the databases was:

```
localhost\SQLEXPRESS2012
```

vs.

```
DAVIDDONAHU436A\SQLEXPRESS2012
```

If this was a networked environment, I'd assume that the named host wasn't the local host.  But this is a sandboxed VM.  I've confirmed that the host in question is that name.  Somehow there are two SQL instances with the same name on the same host bound to different host name entries.

Weird.

Comment: To add to the weirdness... After re-starting SQL Management Studio and connecting to both of the aforementioned addresses, _both_ now show the correct database (indeed, the same database, as changes to one are reflected in the other).  Sounds like some odd behavior in SQL 2012 or Windows 8 or a combination thereof.

Answer (score -1):

In later versions data isn't stored in aspnet_... but in Users and Roles.  Check more here: [Aspnet web site administration tool, Users table or aspnet_users table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915622/aspnet-web-site-administration-tool-users-table-or-aspnet-users-table)

Comment: Those tables don't exist in the target database.  So what other database would it be using?