# aspnet_regsql tool created additional tables

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

When i used aspnet_regsql tool on my mdf file it created by two copies of some tables. For example UsersInRoles and aspnet_UsersInRoles, Users and aspnet_Users. What does it mean?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915622/aspnet-web-site-administration-tool-users-table-or-aspnet-users-table

Answer (score 0):

The aspnet_regsql tool is used to create an application services database. In this database it will create memebership tables like the ones you mentioned in your question. It is used to store users and user roles, etc, that can be used with the asp.net memebership functionality. Please see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

Kleinkie provided a good link too.

You said it copied two copies of some tables, did you mean two tables with identical names under different schemas? I wasnt aware this was possible with aspnet_regsql.

It is best to utalise these tables with the asp.net memebership modules.